# How to simulate a overcrowed wifi with throttling in Charles Proxy

Tags: throttling, charles-proxy, bandwidth-throttling

I would like to use Charles Proxy throttling ability to simulate an overcrowed network as the one we can find in an exhibition with a lot of people.

I assume there are at least 2 factors that could affect the connection :

- distance to the antenna
- number of people on the antenna

In Charles Proxy I can play with multiple settings:

- bandwidth
- Latency
- MTU
- Reliability
- Stability
- Unstable quality range

The objective is to use those settings to be able to reproduce in lab conditions, the condition I can experience for real in the exhibition.

Are there any other factors that I should take into account ?
What are the most relevant settings to touch ?
What are relevant values for those ?